# Marklogic return selected alphabetical facets

Tags: marklogic, facet

Please advice if I need to use facets or any other type of filters.

> I have Articles with names in Marklogic, I need to filter these names by clicking
>
> to alphabet buttons (A to Z). E.G if I click to  F button it should
> return the articles starting with letter F and ALSO should return
> other Alphabet characters from A ... Z I have used the constrains but
> it hides the other character like you click to G it shows only G and
> other characters are not visible.

```
<constraint name="acronyms_alphabetic_order">
    <range type="xs:string" facet="true" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint">
        <element ns="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/source" name="alphabeticOrder"/>
        <facet-option>limit=26</facet-option>
    </range>
</constraint>
```

FYI I have added **range element index**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the facet is actually working correctly. Facets always represent values matching the search result you have.

I think you will need to make changes to the way you pull up facets, rather than change the facet itself.

I would probably do an extra call to for instance `/v1/values` or `search:values` to pull up the values for that facet passing through a search query in which you omit the filter on `acronyms_alphabetic_order`.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for response.
Be are writing the search engine and extra call will increase performance and also this will not acceptable from our stockholders.
Is there any other way to get all alphabetical characters?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure it would decrease performance. This extra call could be executed in parallel for instance. But if you prefer limiting to one round-trip, you could look into building a custom facet: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_49750. That is however not guaranteed to be faster nor easier..